# MySQL - SQL query with inner join taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'd like to optimise the following query. It takes 150-200 seconds with LIMIT 10 on my dev server to execute it. I can't run it on a production server because execution time is limited.

```
SELECT 
intensive.id AS intensive_id, 
intensive.module_id AS intensive_module_id,  
w.id AS w_id, 
intensive.translation, 
w.name_basic_lang, 
w.image_name, 
w.image_number, 
w.image_ext 
FROM mk_int_module_multiwordssentences intensive
INNER JOIN mk_words w ON intensive.translation= w.name_basic_lang
WHERE w.image_number <> '' AND w.image_number <> -1 AND intensive.img_name IS NULL
GROUP BY intensive.id
```

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will return an error with newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and an unpredictable result with older MySQL versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: As mentioned by @jarlh the query will fail on newer mysql with invalid usage of group by, and assuming that you know how to make it working by disabling `only_full_group_by`, we would still require a result of `EXPLAIN` of the above query, so run `EXPLAIN` followed by the query and share the result here.

Comment: there's a problem with GROUP BY but also if you use a LIMIT 10 you have to specify an ORDER BY ... you have to better explain what's the query is supposed to return

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty 1 SIMPLE intensive ALL PRIMARY,C_FK_Module_ModuleMultiwordsSentences    20532 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 SIMPLE w  ALL     96907 Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)

Comment: When you add `LIMIT 10`, what column(s) do you use in the `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM mk_int_module_multiwordssentences intensive
INNER JOIN mk_words w ON intensive.translation = w.name_basic_lang
and w.image_number <> '' AND w.image_number <> -1 AND intensive.img_name IS NULL 
Group by ...
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would be optimal?

Comment: And I assume the second on should be and?

Comment: Conditions applicable after the join of the tables.
If we put condition in join, less data will be joined = optimized

Comment: anyway, im not sure that's query in question works, there are columns in select, which are not in group by

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check if you have indexes on the columns used in the join condition
2. If image_number does not have any other negative value other than -1, check if you can use

   NVL(w.image_number,0) >= 0

(depends on your application functionality).

3. Please check if the below condition can be combined into single condition

   WHERE w.image_number <> '' AND w.image_number <> -1
   to

   NVL(w.image_number,0) <> -1

Comment: NVL is an Oracle function.